# runtime error -2147024809 (80070057): Resizing shape

Tags: excel, vba

My code pastes a shape onto Sheet1 and tries to resize the width, getting an error on this line below.

Worksheets("Global Quarterly").Shapes(Picture1).Width = 1607.76

```
GlobalFile.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("B25")
Selection.Name = "Picture1"
Worksheets("Global Quarterly").Shapes(Picture1).Width = 1607.76
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: change the code to `Worksheets("Global Quarterly").Shapes("Picture1").Width = 1607.76`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Option Explicit` is likely missing, making `Picture1` an undeclared variable, so at run-time you're passing `Variant/Empty` to the `Worksheet.Shapes` collection's `Item` property getter - and that's neither an index nor the name of a shape, so you get a... well an arguably confusing run-time error: a more instinctive error to throw would have been error 5 here, for "invalid parameter or procedure call" - it's the `Shapes.Item` member (implicit) that's throwing; execution never even gets to the `Shape.Width` member call.

Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module; that will make your code uncompilable until all variables are declared, which helps prevent typos and forces a minimal rigor in variable usage.

If the name of the shape is `"Picture1"` (note the string delimiters / double-quotes), then you need to do [as Lodi hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405419/runtime-error-2147024809-80070057-resizing-shape#comment95621514_54405419):

```
Worksheets("Global Quarterly").Shapes("Picture1").Width = 1607.76
```

Comment: @Lodi & Mathieu Guindon - Thank you so much. The error was due to missing quotations. I have been spinning my head for days trying to debug this error. I am new to this, so will need to learn more about "Option Explicit", but thanks again!!